# bundle +50% file size when using {async: true} within CommonsChunkPlugin

Tags: webpack, async-await

As far as the image goes, I wanted to do the same, i.e. dynamic loading of dependencies.

[image: sad]

I managed to do that, I set up my webpack config, added babel-runtime transformer, babel-preset-stage-0 in order to use async/await. Everything worked.

**BUT**

Once I set up my webpack config and its `CommonsChunkPlugin` with an option `{ async: true }`, my production bundle was loaded up with +800KB of code  (currently our production bundle css+js+img = 2mb, by then, it was around 3mb :/ )

The only thing that had anything to do with loading up my bundle size was this option `async: true`. This filesize increase is without changes in the code, just the webpack config.

Anybody experienced the same?

My webpack prod. config https://gist.github.com/hanakivan/22e8131967dc1060fe260d196a0bba7d